# how to move scrollbar of aspxsplitter from right to left

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I want to show scrollbar of aspxsplliter on the left page.
how can I do it?
I search alot but I couldn't find any solution for this problem.
thnx

Comment: elaborate more.. or attach an image that what do you want to do with splitter control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxperienceDemos/Splitter/ScrollBars.aspx) demo. It seems that is what you need.

Comment: no... if you see, all vertical scrollbar are in the right side.. I want to show this scrolls on the left side

Comment: Set the property [RightToLeft](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxSplitterASPxSplitter_RightToLefttopic) to Left.